# How to design a button with elevation effect

Tags: android, android-elevation

I am currently learning android  and wanted to make a button that has elevation effect in it.
To be more precise I want elevation effect like the image below.

[image]

Can anyone help me on how to make this type of button in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Add a XML file in drawable folder and name it a.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Gray shadow. -->
   <item android:left="3dp" android:top="5dp">
      <shape>
         <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
         <corners android:radius="15dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
<!-- White foreground. -->
   <item android:bottom="5dp" android:right="3dp">
      <shape>
         <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
         <corners android:radius="15dp" />
      </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Add in your button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:ackground="@drawable/a.xml"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Output:

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below line to Button tag in xml. It will add elevation as you wanted.

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```